# Mysql join to display only unique ids

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am trying to use an sql query but i get multiple times the same result.

I read that i have to use an INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN to avoid that. The only problem is that i am a bit newbie with mysql so i can't actually make a successful query.

The query is this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1,table2 
WHERE table1.name LIKE '%$str%' 
OR 
table1.last_name LIKE '%$str%'
```

`$str` is a string that i pass in a php function in order to make a search.

Comment: What data do you need from `table2`? Otherwise, I see no reason for a `JOIN`. Back up and tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: I actually need to display some of table2 rows. I have a foreign key in table2 that is the id of table1. I don't know if there is another better way to do that. If there is please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a join between those two tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
   ON table1.key = table2.key
WHERE table1.name LIKE '%$str%' 
OR 
table1.last_name LIKE '$str%'
```

You should also protect against SQL injection by using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
   ON table1.key = table2.key
WHERE table1.name LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($str) ."%' 
OR 
table1.last_name LIKE  '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($str) ."%'";
```

Here is the documentation on the [escape string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1,*, t2.* 
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.table1_id 
WHERE 
    table1.name LIKE '%$str%' OR 
    table1.last_name LIKE '%$str%'
```